# Reading from file in c++

Tags: c++

Im trying to learn a bit about c++ and have run in to some trouble.

I have the following code:

```
char board[5][5];
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("c:/test.txt");

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)    
{
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) 
    {
        while (myReadFile.good())     
        {
            board[i][j] = myReadFile.get();                 
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
    }
}
myReadFile.close();

for(int x=0; x<5; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<5; y++)
    {
        
        cout << board[x][y];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Now i was expecting the first loop to read the chars from the txt file and this works, so yeah!
But the second loop, i was expecting to print the same char back to cout. However this was not the case, so i add the line

```
cout << board[i][j]
```

to the first loop to see if they where loading correctly.
This is the result i get

[image: results]
<sub>(source: [tbmilena.dk](http://tbmilena.dk/test.png))</sub>

Can someone explain why the second loop isn't printing the same as the first.

Comment: could you post text.txt file contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are replacing  board[i][j] immediately after reading a char from file. Put the while loop as the outer most loop.

```
 while (myReadFile.good())     
        {
            board[i][j] = myReadFile.get();                 
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
```

Here, it continuously replaces board[i][j] with new character while i & j remains the same.

Comment: An additional problem is that `myReadFile.good()` tests if the *previous* read worked, not if the *next* `get()` will work.

Comment: good() returns true if none of (errorbit, failbit & eofbit) is set. So it can be used to like "read until eof". Your statement "if previous read worked" takes only failbit into consideration. But good() is better than that.

Comment: No, it doesn't tell if the next `get()` will reach eof. When reading one char at a time, you don't know if there is a next char.

Comment: yes you are right, itdoesn't tell that. A simple check can be added if next read is success after rewriting the original code inside the begniing of the while loop.